# Check if value exists in file

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to read the following file line by line and check if a value exists in the file. What I am trying currently is not working. What am I doing wrong?

If the value exists I do nothing. If it does not then I write it to the file.

file.txt:

```
123
345
234
556
654
654
```

Code:

```
file = open("file.txt", "a+")
lines = file.readlines()
value = '345'
if value in lines:
    print('val ready exists in file')
else:
    # write to file
    file.write(value)
```

Comment: `readlines()` returns the lines *with the trailing `\n` intact*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- `.readlines()` returns lines with `\n` not trimmed, so your check will not work properly.
- `a+` mode opens a file with position set to **the end of the file**. So your `readlines()` currently returns an empty list!

Here is a direct fixed version of your code, also adding context manager to auto-close the file

```
value = '345'
with open("file.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.seek(0) # set position to start of file
    lines = file.read().splitlines() # now we won't have those newlines
    if value in lines:
        print('val ready exists in file')
    else:
        # write to file
        file.write(value + "\n") # in append mode writes will always go to the end, so no need to seek() here
```

However, I agree with @RoadRunner that better is to just use `r+` mode; then you don't need the `seek(0)`. But the cleanest is just to split out your read and write phases completely, so you don't run into file position problems.

Comment: thanks! youre right the problem was opening the file in 'a+' mode that kept giving me an empty list

Comment: You correctly describe that using `'a+'` is wrong here, yet rather than fix it, your answer works around it in a convoluted way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I dont understand. is using 'a+' wrong? I want to append the new value to the end of the file

Comment: @user3702643 Yeah it’s wrong because `'a+'` means “open the file for appending and reading at the end”. In truth, the fact that this file mode exists doesn’t really make sense. Check RoadRunner’s answer, which is using the appropriate mode.

Comment: Note that in `r+` mode there is also an implicit setting of position. It starts at zero, `read()` moves it to end, and then you `write()` at the end. If you move the `write()` before the `read()`, then you'll again run into a surprise: it'll write at the beginnnig. For this reason the cleanest solution here is to split out the read and write phases. @KonradRudolph

Comment: @CihanCeyhan I generally agree but splitting reading and writing has performance implications — though these are presumably tiny; nevertheless, update mode exists precisely to *avoid* having to reopen a file.

Comment: Agreed. And in update mode, you'll have to be careful about your file position; no matter if you use `r+` or `a+`. Using the latter gives you the guarantee that your writes will always go to the end of file, which is valuable. So it's not clear whether one is preferable to other in this scenario. Though I agree with you; I like that with `r+` we don't need the `seek(0)` for this specific question. @KonradRudolph

Answer (score 6):

I would consider several changes.

1: Use `with` to automatically close the file.
2: Use `strip()` to remove leading or trailing stuff, like `\n`
3: Use a `break` for the loop.
4: Add `\n` in the `write` part.

```
value = "345"
with open("file.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.seek(0)
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line.strip("\n") == value:
            print('val ready exists in file')
            break
    else:
        # write to file
        file.write(f"\n{value}")
```

Comment: when I print line I dont get any output. Do you know why? for line in file.readlines() print line

Comment: Just two syntax errors as somehow my copy/paste didn't get the `:` symbols copied from where I tested it. Fixed. The code works, btw.

Answer (score 3):

when working with io the recomended approach is to use the `context manager`. `Context managers` allow you to allocate and release resources precisely when you want to. The most widely used example of context managers is the `with` statement. if you have a large file better not to use `file.readlines()` or the `read()` method. The `readlines()` method returns a `list` containing each line in the file as a list item. better to iterate on the file stream line by line (generator). always use try except with io operations! :

```
values=['123','233'...]
try:
    with open("file.txt", "r+") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            for val in values:
                if val not in line.strip():
                    fp.write(val)
                else:
                    print('val ready exists in file')
except (OSError,...): #catch what ever you think this code above can raise, and re raise in except block if you want.
#do exception handling
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to open the file for reading and writing, I suggest using the `r+` mode from [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open). This will open the file at the beginning of the file, since we want to first read all lines. Using `a+` will open the file for reading and writing at the end of the file, which will cause `lines` to give you an empty list from `readlines()`.

You also need to strip newlines from `lines` before checking if the value exists. This is because `345` is not equal to `345/n`.  We can use a list comprehension to strip the newlines from `lines` using [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), which strips whitespace from the right. Additionally, If you have to do repetitive lookups for multiple values, it might be worth converting `lines` to a `set` for constant time lookups, instead of doing a linear search with a list.

Its also worth using [With Statement Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) when reading files, since the closing of the file is handled for you.

```py
value = '345'

with open("file.txt", mode="r+") as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file.readlines()]

    if value in lines:
        print('value ready exists in file')
    else:
        file.write(f"{value}\n")
```

The other choice is to use `f.seek(0)` with `a+` to set the position at the beginning of the file, as shown in [@Cihan Ceyhan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740922/python-check-if-value-exists-in-file/62741146#62741146) answer. However I think this overcomplicates things, and its just easier to use the `r+` mode.

Comment: This is a good answer, except for the fact that it violates POSIX conventions, which mandates that all lines are delimited by newline. It would be more correct to change the last line to `.write(f"{value}\n")`. As is, the code breaks files on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :)

```
filename = 'file.txt'
value = '345'

with open(filename) as f:
    if value in f.read(): # read if value is in file 
        print('Value is in the file')
```

This will check if the value is in the file and if it's not there. It will add value to the file.

```
filename = 'file_1.txt'
value = '999'

with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    if value in f.read():
        print(f"Value {value} is in the file")
    else:
        print("The value not in the file.\nTherefore, saving the value in the file.")
        f.write(f"{value}\n")
```

Comment: when I print the value of 'value' it gives me the numbers one by one. So instead of 345 I get 3 then 4 then 5 each in a new line. for value in f.read() is what i did

Comment: Not sure what is the reason for that I would have to see your updated code. But I updated mine, it should help. If you don't understand something. I can explain it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are opening file in "`a+`" mode the file cursor from where the `readlines()` method will start reading will be at the end so `readlines` would read nothing. You need to do `f.seek(0)` in order to move the cursor to the beginning.

```
file = open("file.txt", "a+")
file.seek(0)
lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
print(lines)

value = '345'
if value in lines:
    print('val ready exists in file')
else:
    print("else")
    # write to file
    file.write(value)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python script works for me properly. I guess the last line in the else statement should be  `file.write(value)` instead of  `file.write(val)`.

Comment: that was a typo sorry! fixed it

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. The OPs code will also not work after this typo fix, as shown by the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The readlines() method returns a list containing \n with each element so when the condition is checked it is not compared with value with \n so the statement is always false so i have a code that solve your problem.

```
f_name = "file.txt"
text = "102"
def check_in_file(file_name, value):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            if value in line:
                return True
    return False
if check_in_file(f_name, text):
    print('Yes, string found in file')
else:
    print('String not found in file')
    file = open(f_name, 'a')
    file.write("\n"+text)
    file.close()
```